# What are .ini files used for, in PHP?

Tags: php, ini

Can anyone tell me what you can use an `.ini` file in PHP for?

I can see the point that you can make some kind of a config file that's easy to change. But what is the main thing you are using `.ini` file for in PHP?

If you navigate to the location of the `.ini` file, your browser will display it in plain text, which means, it would be stupid to store important/private information like database connection, password and so on in an `.ini` file.

Comment: Most people don't store their config files in the web root...

Comment: okey :) but why use it? whats the meaning ?

Comment: You might use it to store database access credentials, or language settings, or almost any settings that are configurable on a site by site basis.... and if you allow external access to your ini file, you're doing something very wrong

Comment: It's a common and well-understood file format, and often a natural choice for setting stores. In PHP it's typically used in lieu of a more query-overheadish database store, and because .php config files are presumed less reliable to edit.

Comment: you might be browsing the .ini file, in your local system. and it should not be browsable if accessed by web.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An INI file is, as you noted, a convenient way of storing configuration information.  It's a well known format that many people can just use without thinking.

Yes, it is stupid to store sensitive information in any file that can be directly read by a web browser, so you should never ever place your .ini file inside the directory structure of the website.

Also, remember that PHP isn't just for writing web pages.  It is a full blown scripting language which can be used to write applications, especially command-line ones.  For these it is often vital to have some configuration information (on linux you may store it, for example, in /etc) so that when you run the script it does what you want it to do on the data you want it to do it on.

The alternative would be to store configuration data within a PHP file itself, which is more awkward for the novice user to edit.